# How can I avoid using the singleton pattern in my REST API-based game?

Tags: c++, rest, design-patterns, singleton, service-locator

I'm working on a small, turn-based, two-player game written in C++ on top of Cocos2d-x. I have a full REST API established, and I am looking at designs for implementing the client side.

When a user opens the game, she will be displayed a list of her currently active games. This list should be cached, but a refresh must be attempted before the list is displayed. Whenever she taps on one of the games in that list, the game will be loaded. Thus, the game states will also have to be cached. Nothing unusual here.

Now, I'd like to avoid constructing url's and using the cocos2d-x `HttpRequest` and `HttpClient` classes from client code. Moreover, the code for maintaining a list of games, refreshing said list, fetching a certain game state, and pushing game state to the server could easily fit into a Singleton. Let's imagine we have such an object, and we call it `GameLobby` in lack of a better name.

In my mind, these related actions call for a single, encapsulating class instance, so Singleton seems to fit the bill. Passing a reference to a `GameLobby` around just doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It would basically mean that I have to pass it to every `cocos2d::Scene` in my game that needs to know anything about the state of the active games, fetching game state from the server, etc. However, as I've come to understand, the Singleton pattern has become more of an anti-pattern over the years.

Would I be better of using a Service Locator? What about other patterns - are there any relevant that comes to mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good nights sleep, it occurred to me that I don't want to create a monolithic singleton. Not necessarily because it is a singleton, the emphasis is on monolithic. Having a single class implement all the game list and individual game state transaction logic feels like a serious violation of the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

So, here's a quick and dirty class diagram of what I'd like to implement:

[image]

`GameListScene` will be responsible for holding a `GameList` instance. This is the only scene in the game that will expose the list to the user, and so there's no current requirement that says it has to be passed around. The `GameScene` instance is going to be where the action takes place. Both `GameList` and `Game` will be responsible for talking to the REST API. One of my reasons for going with the singleton, was to hide the url and http stuff from the client (`GameListScene` and `GameScene`). In order to accomplish this, I've decided to let them inherit from `RESTClient`. This way, I can keep at least keep the http stuff hidden while not repeating myself.

The bottom line is: I've got more classes with this design, but hopefully it'll prove to be a cleaner and easier to maintain.